# Pandas to_csv with ZIP compresses whole directory

Tags: pandas

```
df.to_csv("/path/to/destination.zip", compression="zip")
```

The above line will generate a file called `destination.zip` in the directory `/path/to/`.

Decompressing the ZIP file, will result in a directory structure `path/to/destination.zip` where `destination.zip` is the CSV file.
Why is the `path/to/` folder structure included in the compressed file? Is there any way to avoid this?
Was blown away by this, currently writing the ZIP locally (`destination.zip`) and using `os.rename` to move it to the desired location.. Is this a bug ?